# python3 can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python-3.x

```
key = key * (len(s) / len(key) + 1)
return ''.join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y) for (x,y) in zip(s, key))
```

Anyone know what could be wrong or have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, can you add the traceback to the question? If not, can you describe exactly what your code is doing wrong?

Comment: i convert project to 2 to 3, error in line 75: https://github.com/sslab-gatech/avpass/blob/master/src/modules/strputil.py

Comment: Please paste the full traceback into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your source code, my assumption is that you are multiplying a string (in your code, `key`) with a `float`, as regular division yields `float`s instead of `int`s. To fix this problem, a likely solution involves using integer division instead of normal division:

```
key = key * (len(s) // len(key) + 1)
```

---

You can also shorten the code as such:

```
key *= len(s) // len(key) + 1
```

Comment: In this case... it would appear the OP could just use `from itertools import cycle` and `return ''.join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y) for (x,y) in zip(s, cycle(key))`

Comment: second error appear in this line : return ''.join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y) for (x,y) in zip(s, cycle(key)))) : an integer is required (got type of generator)